# Could anyone please provide a reference to use Kibana 3.0 UI?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am struggling to use KIBANA UI which provide 3 kind of presentation.
1. blank 2. configure yourself 3. set some data from ES.

I can use elastic search for a data by creating index, but how can i show to KIBANA... i.e to show the search result to KIBANA UI...

Please help.....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the kibana documentation: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html